# How can I call the individual parts of the position attribute vector (X, Y, and Z) as values in geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

When working with geometry nodes, I know that *Separate to XYZ* can be used to separate vectors such as *Object Info > Position Vector* into its three individual components, but I'm unsure how to separate the attribute *Position* vector into its three component values.

I can split the position attribute vector `x,y,z` into `x,0,0`, `0,y,0` and `0,0,z` using attribute math's multiply, but these are still in vector form. I need the values x, y, and z.

I am using Blender 2.92

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Attribute Vector Math **multiplying** `position` with `[1,0,0]`, to get the X component alone, you could take the Attribute Vector Math **dot-product** of `position` and `[1,0,0]`. (Likewise for Y and Z)

However, I think you'd be a lot better off using 2.93 alpha, to get into Geometry Nodes.. you can see what you're doing a lot more easily:

[image]